# Java. Отсортировать даты по месяцам, используя Streams

Tags: java, list, дата, потоки-данных

У меня есть `List<Date>`, с датами в формате `d/MMMM/yyyy`, их нужно отсортировать по месяцам используя `STREAM`.

То есть, если есть:

```
4/February/2020
6/February/1990
11/April/2012
30/August/2011
8/September/2009
25/May/2021
```

То в итоге должно получиться:

```
6/February/1990
4/February/2020
11/April/2012
25/May/2021
30/August/2011
8/September/2009
```

Вот мой код, он просто сортирует по возрастанию:

```
public static List<Date> comp(List<Date> list){

    return list.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Но как сделать как мне нужно я не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно преобразовать в нормальный тип для работы с датой `LocalDate` и отсортировать его, затем преобразовать обратно если нужно возвращать именно `List<Date>`:

```java
public static List<Date> comp(List<Date> list){
    return list.stream()
        .map(d -> d.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate())
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(LocalDate::getMonthValue)
            .thenComparingInt(LocalDate::getYear))
        .map(ld -> Date.from(ld.atStartOfDay()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Тест:

```
6/Feb/1990
4/Feb/2020
11/Apr/2012
25/May/2021
30/Aug/2011
8/Sep/2009
```

Comment: Спасибо, вы очень помогли мне! Все работает как надо

Comment: @Gordey, [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, отметьте его как решение, поставив галочку и/или проголосуйте за ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)