# Exception если в List<Date> есть противоречивая дата. Java

Tags: java, list, исключения, дата, calendar

У меня есть `List<Date>`, с датами в формате `d/MMMM/yyyy`, их нужно обработать, и если есть противоречивая дата(дней больше чем должно быть в месяце), то должно выбрасываться исключение.
То есть, если есть:
`31/February/2021`
То должно выбрасываться исключение. Аргументы метода - строки с годом, днем и месяцев из определенной даты. Вот мой код.

````
public static boolean checkIfIncorrect(String year, String day, String month) throws ParseException {
        int year2 = Integer.parseInt(year);
        int day2 = Integer.parseInt(day);

        
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(month);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        
        int month2 = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year2, month2, day2);

        int daysInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 

        if (day2 > daysInMonth) {
            //Тут должно быть выбрасывание ошибки
            System.out.println("Столько дней в дате: " + day2);
            System.out.println("А столько должно быть в дате: " + daysInMonth);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Все хорошо, кол-во дней в дате не превышает возможное");
        }
        return true;
    }
    ```
````

Comment: вы понимаете, что _дата в формате `d/MM/yyyy`_ - это строка, а не `Date`?  А также, что `Date/Calendar/GregorianCalendar` устарели после выхода хорошего, годного Date/Time API в Java 8 в марте 2014 года?  Вы ведь наверняка пишете на версии Java 17, или немногим меньше.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку в [прошлом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1362977/java-%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-streams) использовалось Stream API, а значит, как минимум Java 8, то и для работы с датами следует применять Java Date/Time API ([вводная статья на Medium](https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-api-time-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-java-c67102497445)).

Касаемо формулировки задачи:

> *У меня есть `List<Date>`, с датами в формате `d/MMMM/yyyy`, их нужно обработать, и если есть противоречивая дата(дней больше чем должно быть в месяце), то должно выбрасываться исключение. То есть, если есть: `31/February/2021` То должно выбрасываться исключение.*

На самом деле, на входе задан список строк `List<String>` в определённом формате, которые нужно распарсить и превратить в список дат.

Для парсинга даты в заданном формате существует класс [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), для которого понадобится установить *строгий* режим определения даты из строки `ResolverStyle.STRICT`, тогда в случае некорректной даты будет выбрасываться требуемое исключение [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html).  Нужно отметить, что это исключение не является checked, и может поэтому использоваться в Stream API.

Также результат можно отсортировать по порядку месяцев, как в прошлом вопросе.

Следует отметить, что `yyyy` в Java 8 означает *год с учётом эры*, а простой год обозначается в формате как `uuuu`.

Поэтому можно либо создать простой форматтер, использующий год `uuuu`

```java
private static final DateTimeFormatter dMMMMuuuu = DateTimeFormatter
        .ofPattern("d/MMMM/uuuu", Locale.US)
        .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
```

либо (если очень нужен формат `yyyy`), использовать `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, в котором установить "нашу эру" по умолчанию:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter dMMMMyyyy = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("d/MMMM/yyyy")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.ERA, 1) // н.э. / AD
        .toFormatter(Locale.US)
        .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
    
public static List<LocalDate> getLocalDateList(List<String> formattedDates) {
    return formattedDates.stream()
        .map(fd -> LocalDate.parse(fd, dMMMMyyyy))
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(LocalDate::getMonthValue)
            .thenComparingInt(LocalDate::getYear)) 
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Тесты:

```java
System.out.println(getLocalDateList(Arrays.asList("30/April/1990", "29/February/2020", "31/February/2000")));
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '31/February/2000' could not be parsed: Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 31'
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:2023)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1958)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:430)
    at MyClass.lambda$getLocalDateList$0(MyClass.java:14)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at MyClass.getLocalDateList(MyClass.java:17)
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:30)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 31'
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.create(LocalDate.java:461)
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.of(LocalDate.java:273)
...
```

Для корректных данных (которые снова форматируются для вывода в исходном формате):

```java
getLocalDateList(Arrays.asList(
    "4/February/2020", "25/May/2021", "8/September/2009", 
    "6/February/1990", "11/April/2012", "30/August/2011"
)).stream().map(dMMMMyyyy::format).forEach(System.out::println);
```

результат будет таким

```
6/February/1990
4/February/2020
11/April/2012
25/May/2021
30/August/2011
8/September/2009
```

---

Следует заметить, что в строгом режиме названия месяцев должны быть написаны с большой буквы (остальные буквы -- строчные).

Comment: Спасибо, за столь развернутый и точный ответ, вы очень помогли снова)
Это как раз такой код, который нужен!

Answer (score 0):

А в чём вопрос?
в месте где у вас написано "//Тут должно быть выбрасывание ошибки" бросайте исключение:

```
throw new ParseException();
```

точнее после вывода сообщений в консоль.

Comment: Код работает плохо, например Август будет 6 месяцем и т д. Не знаю где ошибки

Comment: в каком виде приходит значение августа на вход?
если передать "august", то правильно выводится 7й месяц (с нуля)

Comment: Если брать 29,30 или 31 февраля - то ошибки не будет, и я не знаю почему так

Comment: Для вычисления количества дней месяца, берите 1-е число месяца. Когда вы берёте день, больше возможного, дата перескакивает на следующий месяц.